# Wrap CSV values generated by PHP fputcsv() with “ ”

Tags: php, csv

So, my code generates a CSV file using PHP's built-in fputcsv function

my code

```
$delimiter = ';';
$filename = "members_" . date('Y-m-d') . ".csv";

//create a file pointer
$f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');

//set column headers
$fields = array('"FK"','"ID"', '"Name"', '"Email"', '"Phone"', '"Created"');
fputcsv($f, $fields, $delimiter, ' ');

//move back to beginning of file
fseek($f, 0);

//set headers to download file rather than displayed
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');

//output all remaining data on a file pointer
fpassthru($f);
// }
exit;
```

output :

```
FK;"ID";"Name";"Email";"Phone";"Created"
```

but i want like

```
"FK";"ID";"Name";"Email";"Phone";"Created"
```

please help me

Comment: for me it wrote `"FK";"ID";"Name";"Email";"Phone";"Created"`

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: windows 10 @VladimirVlasov

Comment: Should this not be getting you `[space]"FK"[space];[space]"ID"[space];...`, since you chose that as enclosure…? I would most likely not even bother with fputcsv here, but assemble that line manually and write it using fwrite - not like those columns headers contained any “special chars” to begin with here. (If those are dynamic, might be a different story.)

Comment: How is `$filename` related to all of this? Do you write your data into that file somewhere?

Comment: if i open in notepad he working but if i open excel this not working